# Group by time interval between window of time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure:

```
{  
   "_id":"5c59c35d8610f702d00e6f70",
   "ipAddress":"50.116.14.48",
   "startTime":"2018-02-06T12:01:59.000Z",
   "endTime":"2018-02-06T12:31:00.000Z", 
}
```

I would like to be able to group occurrences within a 15 min window of time. For example; Given the structure of the document above I would assume this document would count as an occurrence for both 0-15mins, 15-30mins, and 30-45mins.

The result would look something like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "occurrences":1,
      "startWindow":"2018-02-06T12:00:00.000Z",
      "endWindow":"2018-02-06T12:15:00.000Z"
   },
   {  
      "occurrences":1,
      "startWindow":"2018-02-06T12:15:01.000Z",
      "endWindow":"2018-02-06T12:30:00.000Z"
   },
   {  
      "occurrences":1,
      "startWindow":"2018-02-06T12:30:01.000Z",
      "endWindow":"2018-02-06T12:45:00.000Z"
   }
]
```

I have seen many examples that group only by a single date on an interval, but how about this situation where the document has a window of time?

How do you build this aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to mickl's time math you need to use [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/range/#exp._S_range) to "spread" the document across all "windows" between start and end:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $addFields: {
        // an array of 15 min intervals between startTime and endTime
        window: { $range: [ 
            { $floor: { $divide: [ { $toLong: { $toDate: "$startTime" } }, 900000 ] }  }, 
            { $ceil: { $divide: [ { $toLong: { $toDate: "$endTime" } }, 900000 ] }  }
        ] }
    } },
    // 1 document per interval
    { $unwind: "$window" },
    // group by interval
    { $group: {
        _id: "$window",
        occurrences: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    // to match expected order
    {$sort: {_id:1}},
    // calculate window boundaries
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        occurrences: 1,
        startWindow: { $toDate: { $add: [ { $multiply: [ "$_id", 900000 ] }, 1000 ] } },
        endWindow: { $toDate: { $multiply: [ { $add: [ "$_id", 1 ] }, 900000 ] } }        
    } }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy if you can operate on miliseconds instead of strings. To convert your `startTime` and `endTime` to the number of miliseconds you can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) and [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/index.html) operators (MongoDB 4.0 or newer).

The formula to "classify" you date to 15-minutes range is also pretty simple: `15` minutes is equal to `900000` miliseconds so you can use [$mod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/index.html) to get the value that needs to be [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/index.html) -ed from original date.

Then from every document you can generate two documents (for `startDate` and `endDate`) using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) them.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            startTime: { $toLong: { $toDate: "$startTime" } },
            endTime: { $toLong: { $toDate: "$endTime" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            ranges: [
                { 
                    start: { $subtract: [ "$startTime", { $mod: [ "$startTime", 900000 ] } ] },
                    end: { $add: [ { $subtract: [ "$startTime", { $mod: [ "$startTime", 900000 ] } ] }, 900000 ] }
                },
                { 
                    start: { $subtract: [ "$endTime", { $mod: [ "$endTime", 900000 ] } ] },
                    end: { $add: [ { $subtract: [ "$endTime", { $mod: [ "$endTime", 900000 ] } ] }, 900000 ] }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$ranges"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$ranges",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            occurences: "$count",
            startWindow: { $toString: { $toDate: "$_id.start" } },
            endWindow: { $toString: { $toDate: "$_id.end" } }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I should have been more detailed. I apologize @mickl. Let's assume the end time is now "2018-02-06T12:31:00.000Z" which means this documents time covers 3 different windows (0-15,15-30,30-45). How do you modify your aggregation to account for this?

Comment: Can't you just add $match as a first stage so that only documents from specified range will remain ? (It should be working fine on strings)